# Azure Pipelines: How to provide app.config?

Tags: .net, azure-devops, app-config, azure-pipelines

Currently I'm building a (pet) .NET project locally. The code is managed via Git. What's local is my `app.config` containing credentials in the `appSettings` section used in unit tests. I don't want to commit this.

Now I want to move to Azure Pipelines to set up automated builds. Of course I don't want to commit my `app.config` so currently it is missing and the build fails because of that.

How would I create the `app.config` (or something similar?) in Azure Pipelines?

Comment: Important terminology note: if your tests require credentials from an app.config, *they aren't unit tests*. Unit tests run in isolation with no dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

You can store the credentials in the Build pipeline variables (make the password secret), then write a PowerShell script that create the `app.config` file and take the credentials from the variables.

PowerShell can use the variables in this way:

```
# Assuming the build variables are 'userName' and 'password'
$userName = $env:userName
$password = $env:password
```

Run the PowerShell during the build (with PowerShell task) and you will get your `app.config` file.